# QTableWidget; Using the celllChanged signal

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, cell, qtablewidget

Im a student programmer using Qt to develop a GUI for work and I have ran into a problem using the QTableWidget. I have a spreadsheet made from this widget that takes various values as user input. I have a QLineedit field outside of this spreadsheet that needs to display a the sum of any values in the 9th column. In this case i thought it would be best to use the [cellchanged signal](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#cellChanged) to add the 9th column together and show set the linedit field to the sum of all these cells. My problem is when I go to execute my application I recieve the following application output and this part in my GUI doesnt work:

```
> Object::connect: No such slot InjectionDialog::addWeightSum(int,int)
> Object::connect:  (sender name:   'tableWidgetInjectionLocations')
> Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'InjectionDialog')
```

I have made sure many times that this slot does in fact exist and is called correctly to the best of my knowledge. However I am a student and maybe I am not right and now I'm here.

my InjectionDialog.h contains the following slots;

```
private slots:
    void accepted_Clicked();
    void cancel_Clicked();
    void useFluidiFileRdoBtn_Clicked();
    void useFluidSpecifiedValuesRdoBtn_Clicked();
    void useParticleiFileRdoBtn_Clicked();
    void useParticleSpecifiedValuesRdoBtn_Clicked();
    void particleInjectionRdoBtn_Clicked();
    void liquidDropletsRdoBtn_Clicked();
    void addWeightSum(int &row, int &col);
```

my injectiondialog.cpp contains the following.

```
InjectionDialog::InjectionDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InjectionDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButtonAccept, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(accepted_Clicked()));
    connect(ui->pushButtonCancel, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(cancel_Clicked()));
    connect(ui->radioButtonUseiFileFluidInjection, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(useFluidiFileRdoBtn_Clicked()));
    connect(ui->radioButtonUseSpecifiedValuesFluidInjection, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(useFluidSpecifiedValuesRdoBtn_Clicked()));
    connect(ui->radioButtonUseiFileParticleInjection, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(useParticleiFileRdoBtn_Clicked()));
    connect(ui->radioButtonUseSpecifiedValuesParitcleInjection, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(useParticleSpecifiedValuesRdoBtn_Clicked()));
    connect(ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int,int)), this, SLOT(addWeightSum(int &row, int &col)));
```

My injection dialog also include my function for adding this column; it is as follows:

```
void InjectionDialog::addWeightSum(int &row, int &col)
{
    double weightSum;
    double totalWeightSum;
    QString tempstr;
    bool check;
    if(col == 9)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->rowCount(); i++)
        {
            if (ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->item(i,9)->text() != "")
            {
                tempstr = ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->item(i,9)->text();
                weightSum = tempstr.toDouble(&check);
                if(check == false)
                {
                    ui->lineEditWeightSum->setText("Error");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    totalWeightSum += weightSum;
                }
            }
        }
        ui->lineEditWeightSum->clear();
        tempstr.append(QString("%1").arg(totalWeightSum));
        ui->lineEditWeightSum->setText(tempstr);
    }

}
```

This issue could be caused by something simple that I'm just not seeing. I appreciate any help that you can offer. Please only leave constructive feed back as I am only interested in improving and accomplishing my goals here. In that regard I appreciate all attempts to assist and thank you for reading this.

Comment: I am not that experienced at Qt but maybe the problem is the references. Did you try to rewrite addWeightSum to get the arguments passed by value instead of reference?

Comment: Indeed I did, same issue.. which makes me think that the application doesn't even get that far. because I should have an error with one of those parameter methods

Comment: Did you clean the project? Maybe your build environment is somehow polluted by old binaries that introduce errors. Although this is highly unlikely.

Comment: I agree with Nobody. Sometimes you if don't rebuild from scratch Qt can throw some unexpected surprises.

Comment: Passing arguments by reference in a slot is useless when using connect anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You signal slot signatures differ. In your declaration of `void addWeightSum(int &row, int &col);`

you have put references. Remove them. `void addWeightSum(int row, int col);`

Comment: I don't see where the signatures differ; I also was under the idea that I needed to reference this value because it originates in the cellchanged signal. I did remove my & and ran a clean before compiling and I'm still receiving the same Application output every time I launch the dialog.

Comment: That would surprise me, can you post updated header for your class

Comment: I actually solved this; The problem was the parameters in the connect statement. For some reason it only works with int, int in both sets of parameters. Strange. Thanks for your help.